# How to write on FAT32 and NTFS from Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, ntfs, filesystem, fat32

What is the best free software for OS X Mountain Lion for enabling write support for FAT32 and NTFS?

Comment: OSX can read + write to fat32, just NTFS is read-only (without some 3rd party software). If you use Win7 you could try to use exFAT (allows for files > 4GB and is write- and readable on win7/osx

Comment: @mark - Let's keep them linked and open. Yes - the answers might overlap, but we can update Lion as versions change and keep this one current (for now)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the moment, the only free way for NTFS write access without using abandoned software is using [NTFS-3G](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) along with [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com). There's a [guide](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/NTFS-3G) for that in the FUSE for OS X wiki.

If you need NTFS writing a lot you might be better off using [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/products/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac/) or [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/), both commercial but more faster and more bulletproof solutions.

As pointed out in the comments, there's no write restriction for FAT32 volumes in OS X.

Comment: I made this work on OS X 10.8.5 (12F37), but it was clunky. I installed FUSE for OS X, then downloaded and compiled NTFS-3G _from source_ (`./configure && make && make install`), then ran `sudo umount /dev/disk2s1` and `sudo ntfs-3g -o rw,nobrowse /dev/disk2s1 /Volumes/MyNTFSDrive`. Also noteworthy: NTFS-3G requires that you mount the desired _partition,_ not the entire _disk._

Answer (score 6):

Try NTFS-FREE, works for me on ML:

This program allows MacOSX to access Microsoft NTFS formatted harddrives connected by USB port. A modified version of the original Linux code, this program is packaged as a easy-to-use installer so that normal users can install it without hassle

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ntfsfree/

Comment: This works without problems in Mountain Lion. It's free, which is always better than paying $20 ~ $30 for something so basic :)

Comment: This is the best option so far. Worked like a charm, simple install, hassle free.

Answer (score 5):

Fuse4x + Ntfs-3g works on OS X Lion. All freeware.

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).
2. In Terminal, type `brew install Fuse4x`.
3. Next, type `brew install ntfs-3g`.
4. Type `brew info fuse4x-kext` . Enter the 2 lines of `$ sudo` code separately at the start of the text given.
5. Type `brew info ntfs-3g` . Enter the 2 lines of code separately after the line "To replace the default Mac OSX automounter:" .
6. A restart may be prompted.
7. Done.

All the best.

Comment: worked perfectly on 10.8.3

Answer (score 0):

As for me I use [Paragon NTFS for Mac](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/product_performance.html). Firstly, it is very fast, secondly, I can rely on it and I'm sure that it won't corrupt my files. Yes, it is commercial with 10-day trial but it is worth spending money. Moreover, it is cheaper than Tusera NTFS!